# Eclipse Imports Ant Build Incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

As someone who is new to Java and developing a plugin for Datameer, I'm not sure if Eclipse has imported the project structure correctly. It doesn't look like it. The nested src folders are split out separately as what looks like Java packages. The Jar files requested by the [plugin sdk](http://www.datameer.com/documentation/display/DAS20/Using+the+Plug-in+SDK)are not in a lib folder, they're included at the top level of the project.

The project requests Java 1.7. I'm using Eclipse Mars with Java 1.8. Although, I have Java 1.7 on my machine so it should only matter when I go to build. Could you please help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate posting answers to my own questions but the issue does appear to be resolved after I switched over to Java 1.7 & restarted eclipse. You can have multiple versions of Java by using `update-alternatives` on Fedora 22. I can't speak to other distributions. Since the project did require Java 1.7 then this outcome makes sense to me